# Manual Partition for Ubuntu 16.04 on 500GB SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

here's another Partition question. I'm installing Ubuntu ONLY on a 500 GB SSD. I have Windows 7 installed on a separate SSD, that uses 3 other HDD's. I only want Ubuntu on the SSD, so I'm trying to figure out the correct partitioning for my system so I can boot between windows 7 or Ubuntu. I have 16 GB of RAM, and I'm not concerned with swapping files between the two OS systems. I've disabled fast boot and secure boot as well. I'm looking for an exact step-by-step for my system. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/301745)

Comment: Since newer system did you reconfigure Windows 7 installer to install in UEFI boot mode or the 35 year old BIOS/MBR? IF not, better to be in UEFI boot mode. But either way also better to have Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows, but use gpt partitioning. But configure Ubuntu SSD as gpt so later you can reconfigure for UEFI. Only use Something Else install option. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)